# Can I stub all the calls to a method but the first one?

Tags: rspec

Using Rspec, is there a way that I can stub all the calls to a method except from the first one?

Example:

```
class Book
  def foo
    "Book#foo()"
  end
end
```

In spec:

```
it 'x' do
  # .... (do something to stub all but the first method call to `Book#foo`)....

  b = Book.new
  expect(b.foo).to eq('Book#foo()') 
  expect(b.foo).to be_nil 
  expect(b.foo).to be_nil 
end
```

Anyone?

Comment: Could you give example, so that we can see what you actually meant ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am learning these now-a-days..examples are much needed to understand stuffs with theory. Thus I asked..

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [ordered expectations](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/MessageExpectation%3aordered) and [call the original method](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method) in the first one.

*Also maybe take a look at [sequences](https://gist.github.com/lukeredpath/1704783)?*

Comment: Instead of link.. Give examples..to explain the concept,, which will make your answer more standalone..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is doable. I haven't actually tested this, but if my memory serves me right this should do it:

```
it 'does some funky stubbing' do
  book = Book.new

  # the first time it will not be stubbed, all subsequent times it will return nil
  allow(book).to receive(:foo) { book.foo, nil }

  expect(book.foo).to eq('Book#foo()') 
  expect(book.foo).to be_nil 
  expect(book.foo).to be_nil 
end
```